# Why is the unit 3 - sphere a subset of the vector space V over the complex field of dimension 2?

Tags: vector-spaces

> The $n$-sphere $S^{n}$ is defined to be $S^{n} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : |x| = r\}$.

For a 3 - sphere, $S^{3} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{4} : |x| = r\}$ and so $S^{3} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{4}$.

How does one then arrive at the conclusion that $S^{3} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{2}$?

Comment: Well there's a natural isomorphism $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ that has all the nice properties ?

Comment: $1=|a+bi|^2+|c+di|^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Comment: @Hermès If you would put your comment as a more complete solution, I will give it an upvote and accept the answer. It's been more than a year since I've graduated - a "short" fresher introduction would help.